# Windows wireless service not running error 193:Oxc1

Tags: wireless-networking, services

I have Lenovo Y 50-70 laptop,windows 8.1, after windows update wifi doesn't work anymore. I checked router, adapter driver and both ok. I try to diagnostic and got massage: windows wireless service not running on this computer. I try to start "WLAN AutoConfig" service, and shows "error 193:OXc1". So I don't know what should I do, Is there somebody can help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a system restore? I know it's not an optimal solution, but I was having the same issue and after countless hours on the phone, 3 Microsoft techs, and one HP tech (who wanted to charge me $90 to help) I did a system restore and that fixed the problem